# NaN counts as false?

Tags: javascript, type-conversion, nan

I'm reading a book "Eloquent JavaScript" by Marijn Haverbeke and it says:

"The rules for converting strings and numbers to Boolean values state that 0, NaN, and the empty string ( "" ) count as false, while all the other values count as true."

Would be very nice if someone explains me what did the author mean by saying that NaN counts as false according to the rules of converting?

As I can see it now:

```
0 == false;     // true
"" == false;    // true
NaN == false;   // false
0 / 0 == false; // false
```

Yes I know that "NaN is not equal to anything, even to the other NaN", but I just wonder what does the book want me to know?

Comment: See more detail here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN

Comment: @Mike, have a look at my solution below with multiple condition checks.

Comment: Thank you, need to get used to the idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, if a variable is assigned to `NaN`, it will evaluate to false if used in a conditional statement.  For example:

```
var b = NaN;

if(b){//code will never enter this block
    console.log('the impossible has occurred!')
}
```

This is true as well if you get invalid input, for example:

```
var input = "abcd"
var num = parseFloat(input);

if(num){
    console.log('the impossible has occurred!')
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but the same is for undefined and null as well?

Comment: Yes, the same is true for undefined, null, an empty string, and the numeric value `0`

Answer (score 1):

```js
var a = NaN;
var b = null;
var c;
var d = false;
var e = 0;

document.write(a + " " + b + " " + c + " " + d + " "+ e + "<br>");
if(a || b || c || d || e){
  document.write("Code won't enter here");
}
if(a || b || c || d || e || true){
  document.write("Code finally enters");
}
```

Reference: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)

Answer (score 1):

Other answers are correct, but the significant thing here is that a conversion to a `bool` takes place in the case that it's used in a condition.

That's why:

```
NaN === false // false
```

Yet:

```
if(NaN) // false because it first does a boolean conversion
        // which is the rule you see described
```

As a side note, `NaN == false` as used in the question (note `==` vs `===`) actually does a type conversion from `false` to `0` per the `==` operator. It's beyond the scope of this question, but the difference in operators is well documented elsewhere.

Comment: How is it possible to compare NaN == false without converting it to a bool then?

Comment: It doesn't convert it in that case, that's why NaN == false is false, the conversion is when you use it as a condition (which makes sense if you think about it, because it must be a bool)

Comment: Here's a cool table btw if you're interested in more rules -> http://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/

Comment: @Mike: When you use `==` to compare against a boolean value, the boolean is actually converted to a number. So `NaN == false` is really `NaN == 0`. *Converting* to a boolean is very different from *comparing* with a boolean.

Comment: @FelixKling This makes sense, thank you for the information!

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks you're right, updated the answer for clarity

Answer (score 0):

The book wants you to know that JavaScript evaluates NaN to false.

```
var notANumber = 500 / 0;
if(notANumber) {
     // this code block does not run
}
else {
        // this code block runs
}
```